# Problem with php variable to using MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Two variables, one is $current_shop another is $shop (see below). Both are printed same value: "sps-app-test.com". But when I use them in the below SQL Update query, the $shop variable works fine by SQL condition, but when using the $current_shop variable, it does not work.

However, the store_url = 'sps-app-test.com'.

I have tried without success, and posted this problem in many other places.

```
$shopify = $_GET;
$current_shop = $shopify['shop'];
print_r($current_shop); // sps-app-test.com

$shop = "sps-app-test.com";
print_r($shop);
    
// form_title
if(!empty($_POST['form_title'])  ){
   
    $form_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 
    $_POST['form_title']);
   
    if( isset($form_title)  ){
        
        $query_form_title = "UPDATE widget_cont SET 
        form_title='$form_title' WHERE store_url='$current_shop'  ";

        echo  $_POST['form_title'];
        
    }
   
    if( !mysqli_query($conn, $query_form_title) ){
        echo "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

[More details in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXmSt.png)

[MySQL row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raoss.png)

Comment: check whether there is/are any extra spaces in the variable, and whether the hyphen is indeed hyphen

Comment: Thanks, But I think there is no problem with spaces or hyphens. Something else I believe.

Comment: You sure there's no spaces? Try this:  ```$current_shop = trim($shopify[‘shop’]);```

Comment: if I print_r($current_shop) this, got the "sps-app-test.myshopify.com"  value. which I wanted. But it does not work when I use it sql query below:

$query_form_title = "UPDATE widget_cont SET form_title='$form_title' WHERE store_url='$current_shop' ";

Comment: @Fly_Moe and yes, after using $current_shop = trim($shopify['shop']) got same value but does not work for sql query.

Comment: you should try printing both the queries and then you will see what's the difference between the two.

Comment: That's the problem, when I print, both print exact same value "sps-app-test.myshopify.com" but the SQL query works for one variable and not for another. I mentioned in the attached Image.

Answer (score 0):

Please try not to include image instead write the code and can you try this :

```
$current_shop = $_GET['shop']
```

since the error is from this one try to use `$_GET` without assign it to a variable

Comment: Unfortunately not works. The SQL query does not work.

Comment: I have updated with more clear details, please check if you can. It's a long time I am trying.

Comment: Can you try this -  $query_form_title = "UPDATE widget_cont SET 
        form_title='" . $form_title . '" WHERE store_url='" . $current_shop . '";